# Can't pass state value into Axios post - React Native

Tags: react-native

I Have A Function `handleSignin` to handle login when button login pressed.

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
 const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
 
  const handleSignin = async () => {
    try {
      const params = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }
      const params2 = {
        email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
        password: 'abcd',
      }

      const res = await clients.post('/api/v1/oauth/login', params)
      if (res.status == 201) {
        console.log('Success')
      } else {
        console.log('Failed')
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle Error Here
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
```

The problem is when i pass `params` into axios a got `401`, but when i hardcode the email and password `params2` i got `201` which mean. its success... the value that i get from state is same with value that i harcode into `params`

Comment: Kindly check both email and password passing as a string that might be an issue.

Comment: @HamasHassan the `typeof(email)` is string

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
 const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  // This function is initialized with an empty email and password string. 
  // You have to pass the parameters async (email, password) => {
  const handleSignin = async () => {
    try {
      const params = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }
      const params2 = {
        email: 'abcd@gmail.com',
        password: 'abcd',
      }

      const res = await clients.post('/api/v1/oauth/login', params)
      if (res.status == 201) {
        console.log('Success')
      } else {
        console.log('Failed')
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle Error Here
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
```